# Kotlin-android-extension communication between Classes similar to Communicating with other Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I have 3 Parts to my Project: A Model that does calculations, some Fragments that display the UI and send Trigger to my third part, the main activity. I did all my Fragments with some interfaces like [Communicating with Other Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

However now I need one of the part of my Model to trigger some UI changes. And I don't know how to do that. Because my goal is to have one part of my Model send or trigger some functions so that the GUI gets updated but it doesn't know the GUI by itself. (it is totally independent from it)
In Main activity I override all the functions

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MimaFragment.elementSelectedListener, InstructionFragment.instructionSaveButtonClickedCallback , OptionFragment.optionSaveButtonClickedCallback, MimaFragment.UITrigger{

override fun abortOptions() {
    extendNormal()
}

override fun updateMima() {
    mimaFragment.updateView()
}
override fun normal() {
        mimaFragment.drawArrows()
}}
```

Fragment exapmle:

```
class OptionFragment : Fragment() {
var optionCallback : optionSaveButtonClickedCallback? = null

interface optionSaveButtonClickedCallback{
        fun updateMima()
        fun abortOptions()
    }

override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        view?.findViewById(R.id.optionsAbort)?.setOnClickListener{

            optionCallback?.abortOptions()
        }
    }

override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        try {
            optionCallback = context as optionSaveButtonClickedCallback
        } catch (e : ClassCastException){
            throw ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implementoptionSaveButtonClickedCallback")
        }
    }
}
```

That is how you usually do it and it works fine. Now to my Question is there a way to do it just like that for a non Fragment class? I tryed it like this:

```
class MimaModul(name: String, description : String, context: Context) : Element(name, description) {
 val uiTrigger : UITrigger? = null

init{
   try {
     uiTrigger = context as UITrigger
   } catch (e : ClassCastException){
     Log.d("ClassCastException","Didn't implement uiTrigger")
     }
}

 fun step(){
 //it does some stuff here and then calls for example
    uiTrigger?.normal()
 }

interface UITrigger{
   fun normal()
}
}
```

However as I expected the UITrigger cast does not work. (it always catches an exception) Do you have any ideas how to solve this. Or how else to do it?
ideally I want MimaFragment to implement the interface. But that didn't work either.

```
class MimaFragment : Fragment(), MimaModul.UITrigger {
//other stuff
override fun normal() {
        drawArrows()
    }
}
```

So when ever my Model is done with a step it should trigger some UI change. And I tryed to avoid just doing a loop and update all Elements based on their status because that would take forever. (Though I see this as my only options at the moment)

Let me know if I was unclear and i shall elaborate.

Comment: by the frist glance at the code, you should probably cast Activity to the interface not Context

Comment: I found that i passed the wrong context. Though How would i do it when I implement the interface by the other class and not the main activity?

Comment: Well, you need to pass an instance (that implements UITrigger interface) to your MimaModul, not the Context. Does not matter if it is an Activity or a Fragment.

Comment: Oh ok that worked. Never Programmed with interfaces like that. I hope it was not a silly Question.